# Does the coupons.com printing uninstaller leave anything behind?

Tags: safari, security, google-chrome, macos

A family member installed the coupons.com printing software on my Mac. Googling around tells me that the uninstaller doesn't fully remove elements of the installation from the Windows version. I haven't been able to find any information on the Mac version, however.

I'm not encouraged by the fact that the installer wants you to quit your browsers before running it, but there are no obvious extensions installed in either Safari or Chrome.

Comment: Try running: `mdfind com.coupons` in Terminal (/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know specifically about the "coupons.com" printing software, but there are some ways to find out if there are some things left behind by the software. These are the best places to look:

- Macintosh HD/Applications/
- Macintosh HD/Library/Internet Plug-Ins
- ~/Library/Application Support/
- ~/Library/Caches/
- ~/Library/Containers/
- ~/Library/Logs (These are just text logs. No
  real trace)
- ~/Library/Preferences/
- ~/Library/Printers/

If you need something more user-friendly or automatized, try the "CleanMyMac" app.

PD: The fact that it needs to quit your browsers it's actually a good thing. It might be removing plugins or extensions.

Comment: Thanks. I checked those locations and didn't find any obvious residue.

Comment: I think it's safe to say that the coupons printing software is gone for good :)

Answer (score 0):

The software is NOT completely removed from your system!

A Closer Look at Coupons.com

http://www.benedelman.org/news/082807-1.html

Is installing a Coupon Printer safe?

http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r20236965-Is-installing-a-Coupon-Printer-safe-